# JDBC ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am creating a dynamic temp table through JDBC but it failed with the error

Query via JDBC:   `create table abcd_tmp  as select * form abcd where 1=2;`

```
 Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

I have checked all other posts in this forum related to this error but of no use. In my case, there is no such table exits with same name. (abcd_tmp in the above example)

I have double verified that there is no such table.  Also even if I change the name from `abcd_tmp` to `abcd_something` , it still doesn't work .   I am pretty sure the error is due to some other reason.. any idea?

Comment: What database product and version exactly? What JDBC driver and version exactly? Do you get the same problem in a brand new database?

Comment: There might be a view, synonym or materialized view with that name. `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'ABCD_TMP'` will tell you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  no records found for the abbove query

Comment: @BasilBourque Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.  The database is not new.

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't say that **table** with that name exists, but **object**. *Object* can be anything - (a table), a procedure/function/trigger/package/sequence/synonym/view/...

You should query `ALL_OBJECTS` or `USER_OBJECTS` to verify what you really have, e.g.

```
SQL> select owner, object_type from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'EMP';

OWNER                          OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
SCOTT                          TABLE

SQL>
```

Then you'll know what you really have.

Comment: I generated a random 15 character name and still it says the same error.. i am thinking it is something to do with permissions? or connection type?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  The issue was due to a logical error in the code. Since I overlooked the log file , I din't realized I am trying to create the same table again and again.. Closing this question.  Thank you all for your prompt help and suggestions.